# Corrupted processing file?

Tags: file, processing, corruption, corrupt

I have a project I've been working on for a long time and a few hours ago when I tried to pick it up from where I left last night I realized that one of the processing files may be corrupted.

Last time I opened this file yesterday it had over 500 lines of code, now it's completely blank. The weird part is that in Properties its memory is displayed to be around 17 KB. I tried opening it with Notepad, but I only got a txt file full of spaces.

Does anyone have any idea how I can recuperate my work? I can't imagine having to rewrite everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how we can help you.

Processing doesn't have auto-backup or anything like that. I'd say make sure you don't have the file open in multiple editors. You could also try sending the file to another computer to see if that works. Other than that, the best thing you can do is check whether your computer has backups of some kind.

Comment: I found this very helpful article meanwhile  https://blog.ktbyte.com/2018/04/09/recovering-lost-processing-sketches/  and I was able to recuperate my cod. I'll let the link here in case someone else will end up in a similar situation.